# Image not deleted even if file.delete() method is called

Tags: java, email, file-io, attachment

I need to send an email along with an embedded image. Once the email has been sent, the image in the application server should be deleted immediately. The problem I'm facing is, after the email is sent, the control goes method which contain,

```
File file = new File("../bar.jpeg")
if(file.exists()){
  file.delete();
  System.out.println("Barcode Image Deleted");
}
```

It's printing "Barcode Image Deleted". But, the image is not deleted and is still present in the same location. I'm using multipart to attach the image to the email.

Why is it not getting deleted?

Answer (score 8):

Are you using javax.mail?
If so, you'll need to wait till the mail has finished being sent, which you find out about by registering a [TransportListener](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/event/TransportListener.html).

This also means you won't be able to use the static Transport.send() methods, but will have to construct and clean up your own session and transport.

I'm trying to remember details from a while ago... I think the DataHandler or DataSource don't close the input stream when they've finished reading it, so you need to keep a reference to it and close it yourself before you can delete the underlying file.

Comment: Yeah. I have given file delete code right after 
             Transport.send(msg);

Shouldn't i???

Comment: Not necessarily, because Transport.send() may not be synchronous. It may teake some time after send() is called before something happens in the background, which is why you need the TransportListener callback.

Answer (score 6):

The [`File.delete`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) method returns a `boolean` which indicates whether the deletion was successful.

It could be that the file deletion is not being successfully performed due to not having permissions to delete the file.

Answer (score 3):

File.delete() returns a true/false condition.  Try checking the return condition of delete to see if the system is actually reporting the file as deleted.

Comment: It wont delete the image file which is been embedded in mail?

Comment: Hi.. I have checked by putting it in if/else block.. It return true only and image not get deleted....

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, File.delete()  returns a boolean if it successfully deletes a file.  Check that value and at least log it.

If it is not being deleted, then I would guess that either

1. the file is currently open for reading and the OS won't let you delete it until it is closed.  Possible your mail software?  My guess is that the mail software does not try to base64 encode the image (for inclusion in the message) until it is actually sending the message...and/or does not stop reading it until the mail is sent.
2. the java process does not have permissions to delete the file

Comment: 1. It wont delete the image file which is been embedded in mail? 
2. I can delete the image before and now only its not deleting!!!

Comment: If your Java code cannot delete the image before the mail is even created, the I could guess a 'permissions' issues.  If your Java code tries to delete the image *immediately* after sending the mail (with image in it), then I would guess that the mail software is still using the image.  How are you sending the mail?

Comment: Yeah. I have given file delete code right after Transport.send(msg); Shouldn't i???

Comment: That is your problem, then!  You need to wait until the message has actually been sent to the SMPT server.

Comment: How do make my controller to wait till that?. One more thing, i have given "file.delete()" in if condition and it goes to true block. i dont know why!!!!

Comment: As @spdenne says, you'll want to use register a TransportListener.  Once the message is actually sent, it will trigger your code, and then you can delete the file.